# Super Noob Question: Getting a returned integer value from a Method

Tags: java, android

This is a super noob question... I created a method that gets a sharedpreference and returns it. However, I don't know how to get and use the integer that is returned by the method.

here is the method:

```
public int getX() {
     return mPrefs.getInt("x", 1);
}
```

How do I call this method in a way that allows me to get and use that integer value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect you're very new to java, so you here comes some basic stuff:

---

The call depends on where you make the call.

In the same class/object you just write (as Olly and Dalex points out)

```
int var = getX()
```

or of course

```
int var
//...
var = getX()
```

---

Outside the object (or in any static method) you need to initialize the object first (as duffymo says)

```
Preferences prefs = new Preferences(); // Or whatever you class is
int value = prefs.getX();
```

---

**BUT:** are you sure you want the shared preferences to be an Object. It might be easier to keep it static. (If you don't know the difference, static is the way =) ). If it's static, you don't have to initialize the object.

To make the method static simply add *static* after the *public* keyword as:

```
public static int getX() {
    return mPrefs.getInt("x", 1);
}
```

The calls will then be:

Locally (same class)

```
int var = getX()
```

Globally (other classes)

```
int var = Preferences.getX()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instanstiate an instance of the class that owns that method and call it:

```
Preferences prefs = new Preferences(); // Or whatever you class is
int value = prefs.getX();  // get the value here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int var=getX();
```

Something like that should work...

Comment: What object or class is this called on?  I don't see one.

Answer (score 0):

```
int iMyValue = getX();
```

Create a variable with the same data type (integer in this case), then assign a value to it using the '=' assignment operator.

Comment: What object or class is this called on?  I don't see one.

Comment: @duffymo, method can be called from inside the class ;)

Comment: And outside....?  It doesn't feel too useful to call a method inside a class to access its own member data.